# Pushing data on git as a first process using TortoiseGit fail on windows 7

Tags: github, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit to manage data on GitHub. But I am facing one problem.

When I start my machine and try to push data using TortoiseGit it fails due to error. But if I clone any project on my machine and after that go for pushing data it works. What will be the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is the full error content?

Comment: Disconnected - no supported authentication method available(server sent public key) this is error

Comment: Nothing works other than clone.

Answer (score 1):

`no supported authentication method available` indicates, that the git client did not provide a SSH public key.

I suppose, when you clone, you have selected a putty key and when you try to fetch/pull/push before no public key is loaded.

1. Load the ssh key manually before doing any git operations by starting putty agent (pageant) and open your ssh key there
2. Automate loading of the SSH key by going to TortoiseGit settings -> Git -> Remote, select your remote there, select your SSH key and save. Now, when you push/fetch/pull make sure the "Autpload putty key" is checked.